# Jenkins/Hudson job push changes to Mercurial

Tags: ant, mercurial, jenkins, automation, push

I have a Jenkins/Hudson that increase some version numbers of some modules in preparation to publish a NetBeans update center to Sourceforge. I'm trying to push those changes into the repository using [ant4hg](http://ant4hg.free.fr) ant task and I'm having some issues. here's that part of the task relevant to this:

```
    <change files here>
    <hg cmd="commit" dir="." message="${message}" user="${hg.user}">
        <dirset dir="./">
            <include name="**/*.mf"/>
        </dirset>
    </hg>
    <hg cmd="push" dir=".">
        <auth user="${hg.user}" password="${hg.password}" />
    </hg>
```

You can see the related bug [here](https://sourceforge.net/apps/mantisbt/ant4hg/view.php?id=13). Anyway, is there a better way to do this from Jenkins/Hudson? Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

I'm trying to push a change and it doesn't work. I tried to use the command as specified in the documentation:

```
    <hg cmd="push" dir=".">
        <auth user="${hg.user}" password="${hg.password}" />
    </hg>
```

But I get:

```
$ hg push
pushing to javydreamercsw@bitbucket.org/javydreamercsw/simple-marauroa-rcp">https://javydreamercsw@bitbucket.org/javydreamercsw/simple-marauroa-rcp [javydreamercsw@bitbucket.org/javydreamercsw/simple-marauroa-rcp" target="_blank">^]
pushing subrepo Card Game Interface to javydreamercsw@bitbucket.org/javydreamercsw/card-game-interface">https://javydreamercsw@bitbucket.org/javydreamercsw/card-game-interface [javydreamercsw@bitbucket.org/javydreamercsw/card-game-interface" target="_blank">^]
searching for changes
no changes found
pushing subrepo Simple Marauroa Java to https://bitbucket.org/javydreamercsw/simple-marauroa-java [^]
searching for changes
no changes found
pushing subrepo jWrestling to https://bitbucket.org/javydreamercsw/jwrestling [^]
searching for changes
no changes found
searching for changes
[ERROR] hg > abort: http authorization required
Result: 255
[ERROR] FAIL TO EXECUTE : hg push (255)
Z:\NetBeans\Simple Marauroa\Marauroa Application Manager\build.xml:680: FAIL TO EXECUTE : hg push (255)
```

If I do it from NetBeans and/or TortoisHg it works. I thought I provided the wrong credentials but I know they are correct.

Previous to that command I do a commit and I get this output:

$ hg commit --include **/*.mf --user xxxxx --message "Update versions for dailybuilds" Z:\NetBeans\Simple Marauroa\Marauroa Application Manager

I pass the same user to the push command adding the correct password as well.

Comment: It looks like your auth info is different for one of your subrepositories.  You should be using ssh-keys w/ bitbucket which will work better w/ Jenkins/Hudson/ant anyway.  Put the full error output in this question (linking to an offsite bug report isn't how things are supposed to work here) and we'll figure it out.

Comment: All subrepositories are hosted in the same bitbucket account. Sadly the ant4hg task seems not to support ssh-keys authentication.